# ¿Cómo almaceno varios datos que ingreso a través de un html?

Tags: javascript, html, funciones, bucles

Lo que deseo es que al dar añadir, me vaya agregando los valores al `array`, y que solo pueda hacerlo el numero de veces que ya seleccioné, pero lo que hace mi función es leer los datos de x y y, posteriormente los agrega 3 veces al `array` final, osea tengo solo 1 valor por incógnita repetido 3 veces. De ante mano, gracias uwu

```
<div>
        Número de intervalos:
        <input type="text" id="numero"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Aceptar" id="inicio"><br><br>

        Ingrese X: 
        <input type="text"  id="valorX"> <br><br>
        Ingrese Y: 
        <input type="text" id="valorY"> <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Añadir" id="add">
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Generar tabla" id="mostrar">
    <div id="mostrarNumeros"></div>
```

---

Acá la función:

```
function getDatos(x,y){
    var num=document.getElementById('numero').value;
    var tabla=[];


    for(let i=0;i<num;i++){
    var linea=[];
    var x=document.getElementById('valorX').value;
    var y=document.getElementById('valorY').value;

    linea.push(x,y);
    tabla.push(linea);
    }


    return tabla;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varios problemas con la lógica, o al menos por lo que has enseñado. Si quieres que el número de intervalos se añada con un botón, los valores con otro y que la tabla se muestre con otro, no puedes hacerlo con una única función. Tu código JS debería de parecerse más a esto.

```
  //Inicializo las variables al principio del script
 var tabla=[];
 var num = 0;
 //función que recoge el número de intervalos
 function numIntervalos(){
   num = document.getElementById('numero').value;
 }
 //Función que recoge x e y y los añade a tabla
 function getDatos(){

   for(let i=0;i<num;i++){
     let linea=[];
     let x=document.getElementById('valorX').value;
     let y=document.getElementById('valorY').value;

     linea.push(x,y);
     tabla.push(linea);
}
```

}

Lo siguiente que no veo que hagas por lo que has subido, es el cuándo llamas a la función Para llamar a la función haz uso del `onclick`, y cambia de esta forma los input:

```
<input type="button" value="Aceptar" id="inicio" onclick="numIntervalos()">    
<input type="button" value="Añadir" id="add" onclick="getDatos()">
```

Te he cambiado el type a button porque no tiene sentido el submit sin estar dentro de un formulario. Y he eliminado los párametros x e y ya que luego en la función los recoges mediante el `getElementById()`.

Espero que te haya aclarado un poco el como hacerlo, la llamada a generar la tabla te la dejo a tí. Como comentario adicional, creo que algunos botones sobran y quitarlos te ayudaría a simplificar el código, pero si los tienes por algo sera :D

Un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

Voy a compartir contigo un ejemplo, que si puede no ser el mejor, creo que hace lo que pretendías. Quizá el ejemplo sea extenso y se pueda afinar más, pero supongo que te puedas hacer una idea:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    let addButton = document.getElementById("add");
    let timesButton = document.getElementById("inicio");
    let valorX = document.getElementById("valorX");
    let valorY = document.getElementById("valorY");
    let tabla = [];
    let count = 0;

    timesButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        if(document.getElementById("numero").value.trim() == ""){
            alert("Tienes que introducir una cantidad!!!");
        }else{
            count = document.getElementById("numero").value;
            alert(`Puedes introducir ${count} combinaciones`);
        }
    });

    addButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        if(valorX.value.trim() == "" || valorY.value.trim() == "" || count == 0){
            alert("Debes de introducir todos los valores!!!");
        }else{
            let x = valorX.value;
            let y = valorY.value;   
            getDatos(x, y);
        }       
    });

    function getDatos(x,y){
        if(valorX.value.trim() == "" || valorY.value.trim() == "" || count == 0){
            alert("Te falta algún valor!!");
        }else{
            let linea = [];
            linea.push(x,y);
            tabla.push(linea);
            alert(`Los valores introducidos en la posicion ${tabla.length} son ${x} y ${y}.`);
            if((tabla.length) == count){
                alert("Ya has introducido todas las combinaciones.");
                alert(tabla);
                console.log(tabla);
            }
            return tabla;
        }
    }

});
```

Yo personalmente prefiero no utilizar el atributo "onclick" en el HTML. Creo que la mejor opción sería agregar eventos a los elementos del DOM mediante Javascript.